# Publish from SVN to folder ProjectName_VersionNumber_BuildNumber

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I have a VS 2008 web forms project and I'm using CruiseControl.net to build and test the app. All fairly straight forward.

What I'd like to do is automate the publishing to a given folder, and have the folder named ProjectName_VersionNumber_BuildNumber. I can build to a statically named folder, but I can't see how to name the folder automatically. How can I detect the version number and build number in cruise control scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CruiseControl passes a lot of properties (integration properties they call them) to your tasks. How you use them will depend on which task you are using. For example, here is a [list of the properties for MSBuild](http://ccnetlive.thoughtworks.com/ccnet/doc/CCNET/MsBuild%20Task.html). Here are the properties that I think you want based on your question:

**CCNetLabel:** The label used to identify the CCNet build. This label is generated by the CCNet labeller.

**CCNetProject:** The name of the CCNet project that is being integrated.

All you would have to do is write something like this to create the folder name:

```
${CCNetProject}_${CCNetLabel}
```

The rest of the available integration properties can be found [here](http://build.nauck-it.de/doc/CCNET/Integration%20Properties.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can publish to a subfolder named with the build label - look for `UseLabelSubdirectory` in [the documentation](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Build+Publisher).

Or you could use a [custom task](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Executable+Task) - ccnet will set a bunch of environment variables before executing it, including one for the build label.